# Proposal for Documentation on Programmers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Stack Overflow recently launched their Documentation beta. I propose we make Documentation for Programmers.SE, too.

As Jeff Atwood said in his [blog post,](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/)

> Stack Overflow is for when you're front of your compiler or editor working through code issues. Programmers is for when you're in front of a whiteboard working through higher level conceptual programming issues.

So if we use the same reasoning for Documentation:

Stack Overflow Documentation teaches you how to use `malloc()`, while Programmers Documentation teaches you memory management concepts.

Stack Overflow Documentation teaches you how to create a SQL database entity in PHP, while programmers Documentation teaches you about data structures and their usage.

Should there be Documentation for Programmers too?

Comment: this was [asked and answered at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281690/165773): "the product isn't quite ready to go elsewhere... Once it is known to work, then we can discuss the possibility of adding it to other sites..."

Comment: @gnat this should be the answer actually.

Comment: @maple_shaft [there you go](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/8158/31260) <-- made it into answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was asked and [answered by Community Manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281690/165773) at MSE:

> the product isn't quite ready to go elsewhere... Once it is [known to work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328405/documentation-has-entered-public-beta#comment369176_328405), then we can discuss the possibility of adding it to other sites but that won't be for [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)...

Comment: "the product isn't quite ready" for Stack Overflow, either. It is a rat's nest of users writing poor quality junk in the hopes of gaining easy reputation.